# Trouble with JavaScript async/await functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am a beginner to JS currently doing a project where I am pulling basic information from a Firebase Realtime DB. I have a function which checks how many items there are in the DB and another which gets a specific value. When I check the values they return inside of those methods, its fine - the problem arises when I call them elsewhere. I believe this is due to the asynchronous nature of those functions. I am unsure how to structure them to avoid this problem. I know I need to use Promises and the .then function but I am unsure of how to do so. Here are my two functions:

```
var urls = [];
function gotData(data) {
  var number = randomNumberGenerator();
  dbRefObject.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val().URL;
      urls.push(childData);
    });
  });
}
```

And

```
function randomNumberGenerator() {
  dbRefObject.on("value", (snap) => {
    var totalRecord = snap.numChildren();
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * totalRecord));
  });
}
```

When I put console.log statements inside these methods they work fine - the problem arises when I call them elsewhere. For example, when I call the urls array elsewhere it dosent return anything except 'undefined'. I will be extremely grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you please share how are you calling these elsewhere?

Comment: So for example after I push the URLs to the urls array, I want to use these elsewhere. Right now I am just printing them but it comes back undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`dbRefObject.once` is async in nature(Stream)

```
// This is async in nature
dbRefObject.once("value", function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    var childData = childSnapshot.val().URL;
    urls.push(childData);
  });
});
// urls will be undefined here
```

#### How to access urls,

*Solution:* Using Callback fucntions

```
dbRefObject.once("value", function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    var childData = childSnapshot.val().URL;
    urls.push(childData);
    urlsUpdated(urls)
  });
});

function urlsUpdated(urls) {
  // Do something herer
  console.log(urls)
}
```

Comment: Dosent seem to be working - I added some code in the urlsUpdated function to print out the urls array but it still prints nothing